# Sorting problem cannot instantiate abstract object overriding compareTo() Method

Tags: java

I'm trying to establish a new sort criteria, in this case by name.
I'm facing an error when I call the sort method...

this is a separated class (SortByName) in package "package":

-----------------------CLASS SortByName---------------------------

package package;

import java.util.*;

public abstract class SortByName implements Comparator{

```
public int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2){
    String n1 = ((Ficha)o1).getName();
    String n2 = ((Ficha)o2).getName();
    return n1.compareTo(n2);
```

### }

and then inside an ActionPerformed event I have this:

----------------IN THE ACTION EVENT BUTTON----------------------------

Collections.sort( list , ***new SortByName()*** );

### **"package.SortByName is abstract,> cannot be instantiated"**

I tried changing the "abstract" type in the class definition (SortByName) , but it complies about not overriding the compareTo() method.

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laura you were right I had to add the equals method.( u missed the return value)
also remove "abstract" at class definition.
and change compareTo() with compare().

**thanks a lot Laura, PROBLEM SOLVED !!!!**

Answer (score 6):

The method you have to implement is called `compare`, not `compareTo`.

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

Also, `Comparator` is generic, so you'd better do the following:

```
public class SortByName implements Comparator<Ficha>{

    public int compareTo(Ficha f1, Ficha f2){
        String n1 = f1.getName();
        String n2 = f2.getName();
        return n1.compareTo(n2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparator needs to implement compare(), not compareTo() method.

Answer (score 3):

```
class SortByName implements Comparator<Ficha>{
@Override
public int compare(Ficha o1, Ficha o2) {
    String n1 = o1.getName();
    String n2 = o2.getName();
    return n1.compareTo(n2);
}
```

}

Comment: +1 for the proper post-Java 1.5 way of implementing that interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "abstract" and implement the equals method as well.

Code should look like:

```
package package;

import java.util.*;

public class SortByName implements Comparator{

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
    String n1 = ((Ficha)o1).getName();
    String n2 = ((Ficha)o2).getName();
    return n1.compareTo(n2);
}

public boolean equals(Object o1) {
 // code which compares the current comparator (!) with the object given
}
```

Note that you might need to use specialized comparators if compiling against a version of java which supports generics. Not sure if this is correct but I think you can do something like:

```
public class SortByName implements Comparator <Ficha> {
    public int compare(Ficha o1, Ficha o2){
       // comparing code here
    }
}
```

But again, not entirely sure on that part, you need to test it a bit.

If you check out the [Comparator API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will explain how you must implement equals.

Also note that the Comparator interface defines `compare`, not `compareTo`.

Comment: Why does a comparator need equals ...?

Comment: -1, wrong method name here as well - compareTo instead of compare

Comment: Yes I just noticed and edited appropriately. I don't think it justifies a -1 though

Comment: Well, this was the core of the question. And it was also because implementing 'equals' is not a 'must'. But I withdraw the -1 now.

Comment: -1, equals is not needed, as Collections.sort does not require a comparator consistent with equals. Moreover, a comparator is consistent iff the equals method *of the objects it compares* returns true whenever compare returns 0.

Comment: That is, you are overriding the wrong equals method to make it consistent.

Comment: @meriton, if the interface requires it, it must be there; the fact that you can use the default comparator in class `Object` instead of implementing it yourself does not change the fact that it is required by the interface

Comment: yes.. although this would be one of many, since he obviously isn't too keen on reading documentation.

Comment: @Laura: The interface does not require that a comparator is consistent with equals. And you are missing the point: If consistency is required, he'd have to override `Ficha.equals`, not `SortedByName.equals`